# Date выдает неверные результаты

Tags: java, дата

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddд HHч mmм ssс") ;
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println( format.format(new Date(864000000000L)));
```

Данный пример кода выводит

```
19д 00ч 00м 00с
```

Но 864000000000 секунд = 10000 дням.
В чем же проблема?

Comment: Вы получили дату 1997-05-19T00:00 и выводите день (19), часы (00), минуты (00) и секунды (00). Если нужно вывести 10000, то ответ ниже.

Answer (score 4):

Вы неправильно используете паттерн `dd`. Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) это:

> d - Day in month

Поэтому все вполне логично.

Чтобы получить желаемый результат воспользуйтесь следующим кодом:

```
long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(864000000000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

Остальные дни - в годах и месяцах, которые не включены в формат.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Дата (`Date`) - это метка на календаре и часах, а не промежуток времени.

Comment: Что тогда мне посоветуете сделать?

Comment: @KirillMeøw Выяснить, есть ли в языке Java такие вещи как `Timespan`, `Period` или `Interval`.

Answer (score 0):

864000000000L в милисекундах, а не в секундах

```
/**
 * Allocates a <code>Date</code> object and initializes it to
 * represent the specified number of milliseconds since the
 * standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1,
 * 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
 *
 * @param   date   the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
 * @see     java.lang.System#currentTimeMillis()
 */
public Date(long date) {
    fastTime = date;
}
```